# How to divide by two any columns on CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Here's a code from w3 schools.There are 9 boxes there.But I want to just divide the width of 3rd column of 1st row by two.How can i do this?Here's the code below

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is how it should look:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by dividing ? Do you want two distinct boxes inside your box ?

Comment: picture is on the link you can check https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oiul.jpg

Comment: Yes, I checked it out. But the picture isn't explicit to me. You just want a blue line that divides your box ? Or you want to clearly separate this box and have two boxes ?

Comment: @A.Freb is it ok to have two boxes that take half the space of the container one or you want to split the box into two?

Comment: You would be better of using a CSS framework like twitter bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/ and just inspect the elements from their examples. You'll understand how to build a grid layout

Comment: yes i want to seperate this box and i'd like to have two boxes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Option 1

You need to wrap the new containers in a new `div` and create a **sub-grid**:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="subgrid">
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

#### Note

Please note that due to the `padding: 20px;` these subgrid columns don't fit into the width that is available in the default StackOverflow snippet view, which is why the width is adjusted so the first two regular columns are now less wide than the third containing the subgrid. Even if they were just wide enough, the browser decides how wide to render each column, just like in a  `table` element.

### Option 2

The other option is to have 4 columns defined on the `.grid-container` and then use `grid-column-start: span 2;` on cells 6 and 9. The new grid container would be defined as this if you want equal width columns:

```
grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.colspan-2 {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3.1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item colspan-2">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item colspan-2">9</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ggrid-item can be removed

Comment: Thanks very much also can you help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing this :

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item3 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.grid-subitem {
   background-color: green;
   flex:1;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item3">
        <div class="grid-subitem">3.1</div>
        <div  class="grid-subitem">3.2</div>
    </div>  


    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.div-span{
  width: 20%;
  display:table-cell;
}
.make-border{
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">
     <div class="div-span make-border">Umar</div>
     <div class="div-span">Bilal</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this even close to the indended result?

Comment: I have just given an idea.